# Which Apache2 add-on are these logs from?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, logs

I remember using a logging module or add-on for apache2 to inspect the contents of POST/PUT/GET data coming in and out of my webserver.

Here's a what the log looks like according to a screenshot from then:

```
--80852032-A--
[09/Apr/2018:16:04:31 --0700] Wsvxf6wQyCwAAAajw9gAAAAD 10.6.30.254 11378 10.6.30.44 433
--80852032-B--
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.18.64.136
Accept: */*
testheader: testvalue
Content-Length: 8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

--80852032-C--
testbody
--80852032-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Mar 2013 17:15:18 GMT
ETag: "10d-4d88699718396"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 269
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html

--80852032-E--
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>Server pc44</p>
<p>eth0: 10.6.30.44/24
eth1: 172.16.200.44/24 2001:172:16:200::44/64<p>
<p>Service:
 http 80 8080 443 8443
 ftp 21 2121
 smtp 25 8025 465 8465
 pop3 110 8110 995 8995
 imap 143 8143 933 8993
 samba</p>
```

Answer (score 11):

What you are showing us, are logs generated by Modsecurity.  You can tell they're ModSecurity because of the segment messages that look like this:

```
--6b253045-A--
...
--6b253045-B--
...
--6b253045-C--
...
--6b253045-F--
...
--6b253045-E--
...
--6b253045-H--
...
--6b253045-Z--
```

Modsecurity is a layer-7 firewall/filter on top of Apache, and belongs to a class of security applications known as WAF - Web Application Firewall(s).

The corresponding package is known as `libapache2-mod-security` in Debian and derivative systems (including Ubuntu).

> Package: libapache2-mod-security2
>
> External Resources:
>
> ```
> Homepage [www.modsecurity.org]
> ```
>
> Tighten web applications security for Apache
>
> Modsecurity is an Apache module whose purpose is to tighten the Web
>   application security. Effectively, it is an intrusion detection and
>   prevention system for the web server.
>
> At the moment its main features are:
>
> - Audit log; store full request details in a separate file,
>     including POST
>     payloads.
> - Request filtering; incoming requests can be analysed and offensive
>     requests
>
>   can be rejected (or simply logged, if that is what you want). This feature
>     can be used to prevent many types of attacks (e.g. XSS attacks, SQL
>     injection, ...) and even allow you to run insecure applications on your
>     servers (if you have no other choice, of course).

To install it, you run:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-security
```

#### References

- [ModSecurity Handbook - Logging](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/modsecurity-handbook-free/online/ch04-logging.html)